# how to set output parameter of mysqldataadapter

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, dataadapter

p_maxsi is an output parameter but don't know how shall tell it to .net..

```
 MySqlDataAdapter msdadapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("usp_NewItemId_test", mysqlcon);
 msdadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 msdadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("p_maxsi", MySqlDbType.Decimal);
 // output parameter how
 msdadapter.Fill(dtbl);
```

Please help new to .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this lines helped me. thanks @vaibhav parmar

```
msdadapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("p_maxsi", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `MySqlDataAdapter`  in same we do with `SqlDataAdapter`  :

```
//Create the parameter 
 SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter("p_maxsi", SqlDbType.VarChar);

//Set the parameter direction as output
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(parameter);

SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
sqlAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

//Fetch the output parameter after doing the Fill

string outputValue = Convert.ToString(parameter.Value);
```